# Autodiscover web service on IP address

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl

I've got only IP address of web service like: hxxp://192.168.1.3:7777

and I dont know name of the method

How can I discover which web service is there ?
When I try to add service reference in VS I got no result.
Is there a tool that can list available WS on such address?

Answer (score 0):

You should find the WSDL URL and this way you could retrieve all the info you need regarding the service. The WSDL URL depends on the SOAP implementation you're using, i.g. Axis2 sends the WSDL if you append `?wsdl` to the service URL. In any case you should check the documentation of the SOAP implementation you're using for more on how to reach the WSDL URL.